# Textarea is taking lot of time to validate text when pasted from notepad using RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a jsp page where I am validating the for characters entered in textarea. I pasted the following sentence in textarea:

> Exception (Clause No. 2 pg.).

Then I clicked button which validates the characters entered in textarea. IE hangs for 5 min and after that it gives me desired alert. However if type same thing in textarea alert comes instantly. Code is working fine for firefox.

this code is in .js file

```
function SpecialCharacter(obj){

    if(Trim(obj.value) != "")
    {
        var objRegExp  = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9- \b]+([-:,.&=/a-zA-Z0-9 \b]+)*$");
        var errMsg = "Please enter alpha numeric and following special characters(:,.&=/) only.";
        if (! obj.value.match(objRegExp))
        {
            alert(errMsg);
            obj.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

JSP page

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="100" class="clsMultiLineTextBox" name="XYZ" id="XYZ" ></textarea> 

<input type="button" class="button" onclick="doSubmit();return false;" id="btnPostQuery" value="Post Query">
```

```js
function doSubmit(){
    if(Trim(document.forms[0].XYZ.value).length <= 0 ){
        alert("ABC cannot be empty.");
        return false;
    }else if( Trim(document.forms[0].XYZ.value).length >500){
        alert("Query allows you to enter max 500 characters.");
        return false;
    }else if( !SpecialCharacter(document.forms[0].XYZ)){
        return false;
    }else{
        document.forms[0].hidMode.value="post_query";
        document.forms[0].submit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Kindly advise why this is happening.
Thanks,
Gaurav Chaudhary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because the regexp goes into a loop. Try to find a simpler regexp that terminates faster in case of an error.

Look into `*?` or validate the text in pieces by first matching part of the regexp (the header). If there is no header -> error.

Then strip the header. Search the rest of the input for the inverse of the allowed characters (`[^...allowed chars...]`. If you have a match anywhere -> error